# Passing the id of button to another page

Tags: php

The following is my HTML. I want to pass the name of the dropdownlist(d1and d2) to another survey.php page when the button is  clicked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Survey</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form id="form1" action="survey.php" method="POST">
<table border=1>
<tr>
    <td height=" 30" width="200">
    Condition of the item received:
    <select name="d1">
        <option>Select One</option>
        <option value="g">Good</option>
        <option value="s">bad</option>
        <option value="u">Worst</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td height=" 30" width="200">
        Price of the Item:
    <select name="d2">
        <option>Select One</option>
        <option value="g">Good</option>
        <option value="s">bad</option>
        <option value="u">Worst</option>
    </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center" >
        <input type="button" name="submit1"  value="Submit" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like it already does this. What is the problem?

Comment: You'll find them in the $_POST array on survey.php

Comment: He is saying he wants to pass the text, not the value, as I understand, Place the <option Value= "Good">Good </option>
Is this what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite:

```
        <form id="form1" action="survey.php" method="POST">
        <table border=1>
        <tr>
            <td height=" 30" width="200">
            Condition of the item received:
            <select name="d1">
                <option>Select One</option>
                <option value="Good">Good</option>
                <option value="bad">bad</option>
                <option value="Worst">Worst</option>
            </select>
            </td>

            <td height=" 30" width="200">
                Price of the Item:
            <select name="d2">
                <option>Select One</option>
                <option value="Good">Good</option>
                <option value="bad">bad</option>
                <option value="Worst">Worst</option>
            </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" >
                <input type="button" name="submit1"  value="Submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, instead of:  `<input type="button" name="submit1"  value="Submit" />`

Use:  `<input type="submit" name="submit1"  value="Submit" />`

`<input type="submit">` is what is used to actually send the form.

Secondly, in the body of `survey.php`:

```
<?php
echo "You rated ".$_POST['d1']." for condition."
echo "You rated ".$_POST['d2']." for price."
?>
```

## In short:

The `$_POST` variable in PHP is automatically set to a dictionary containing all the POST parameters.

Comment: I want to get the name of my dropdownlist i.e d1,d2...but not the value of the selected option...